# Python SQLite Insert not working despite commit

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

This is the code I'm running in Python. The table has been created in the DB already. I'm doing a commit, so I don't know why it's working.

The code executes just fine, but no data is inserted into the table. I ran the same insert statement directly via sqlite command line and it worked just fine.

```
import os
import sqlite3

current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
db_file = os.path.join(current_dir, '../data/trips.db')
trips_db = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
c = trips_db.cursor()
print 'inserting data into aggregate tables'
c.execute(
    '''
    insert into route_agg_data
        select
        pickup_loc_id || ">" || dropoff_loc_id as ride_route,
        count(*) as rides_count
        from trip_data
        group by
        pickup_loc_id || ">" || dropoff_loc_id
    '''
    )
trips_db.commit
trips_db.close
```

Comment: Try changing `trips_db.commit` to `trips_db.commit()` and `trips_db.close` to `trips_db.close()`?

Comment: Thanks! This worked!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the last 2 lines of my code to this:

```
trips_db.commit()
trips_db.close()
```

Thanks @thesilkworm

Comment: @Shawn, Please read below link for sp.

[Adding Stored Procedures to SQLite][1]


  [1]: https://web.archive.org/web/20140528151125/http://chriswolf.heroku.com:80/articles/2011/01/26/adding-stored-procedures-to-sqlite

Answer (score -1):

Could you write stored procedure inside sqlite:

Then Try In Python:

```
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.callproc('insert_into_route_agg_data', [request.data['value1'], 
request.data['value2'], request.data['value3'] ] ) 
results = cur.fetchone()  
cur.close()
```